# Errors in script which runs on boot

Tags: linux, boot, script, centos-6

I have made an installer script of my architecture which runs on boot, and I added it to chkconfig:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# chkconfig: 2345 99 30
# description: Product Installer Service
# 
if [ -f /home/installer.sh ]; then 
    sleep 60 
    bash /home/installer.sh > /root/.productlog 2>/root/.productlog 
    rm -f /home/installer.sh 
fi
```

When I run `installer.sh` manually it works perfectly, but on boot it gives a lot of errors:

```
cp: cannot stat 'default/etc/named.conf': No such file or directory
.
cp: cannot stat 'default/var/www/html/index.php': No such file or directory
.
chown: invalid user: 'apache:apache'
cp: cannot stat '/var/lib/mysql': No such file or directory
chown: invalid user: 'mysql:mysql'
/home/installer.sh: line 787: mysql: command not found
.
.
```

Is there any way to fix this?  Could I perhaps use an `@reboot` cron job to run it after boot has completed?

Comment: I think one of your scripts run before file system is ready for use. Are you using full paths in those scripts or relative? Relative is bad idea in this case.

Comment: i use full paths, how to run it after file system is ready?

Comment: i would recommend placing it in rc.local  file. https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-boot-init-shutdown-run-boot.html

Comment: As an aside, why are you testing for a plain file (`test -f`) instead of `test -x`?

Comment: I test if the installer script exist, beacause at the the end of istallation i romve it  `rm -f /home/installer.sh`